# ASP.NET MVC Routing Help Required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

I'm creating a online log viewer application which reads logs generated by many applications into a single common database. Log types are error, fatal, debug and I use all to represent all the logs.

I've a controller named AppsController which should server Views for the following requests, where "bi-reports" is one of the many application names we have.

```
/apps/bi-reports/
/apps/bi-reports/all
/apps/bi-reports/error/
/apps/bi-reports/2011/04/
/apps/bi-reports/2011/04/all
/apps/bi-reports/2011/error
/apps/bi-reports/2011/04/error
/apps/bi-reports/all/last-hundred
/apps/bi-reports/all/most-hundred
/apps/bi-reports/2011/last-hundred
/apps/bi-reports/2011/04/all/last-hundred
```

How should I configure routes set parameters in Action methods of Controller to get this working?

Comment: What is your intended result?  I.e. you want everything after "/apps/" to be treated as a parameter to the method, and retrieve data based on that?

Comment: I would make `most-hundred` `last-hundred` and `all` to be paging parameters. I would also make `all` and `2011` to be querystring parameters. Error should be a "Shared View" that gets pulled up from an ActionFilter. Then you're just left with the `apps` controller and the `bi-reports` action.

Comment: remember, you can send a parameter to an action without using `?myParameter=all` -  you can just skip it and have `/all`

Comment: @rockinthesixstring bi-reports is a application name, it could be anything that is a valid application name / id.

Comment: I posted my answer before I read your comment. So what are you working with regarding your Controller and Action? Are you reusing the same view for all of the data, or do you have a separate controller for 2011, 2012, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rough idea of your routing definition. I can see that you basically have three types of routes:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "IrrelevantDates",
    "{controller}/{application}/{type}/{range}",
    // defaults
    new {
        controller = "Apps",
        action = "UnboundReport",
        type = "all",
        range = "no-limit"
    },
    // constraints
    new {
        type = "apps|error"
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "RelevantYearOnly",
    "{controller}/{application}/{year}/{type}/{range}",
    // defaults
    new {
        controller = "Apps",
        action = "YearlyReport",
        type = "all",
        range = "no-limit"
    },
    // constraints
    new {
        year = "19\d{2}|2[01]\d{2}",
        type = "apps|error"
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "RelevantYearAndMonth",
    "{controller}/{application}/{year}/{month}/{type}/{range}",
    // defaults
    new {
        controller = "Apps",
        action = "MonthlyReport",
        type = "all",
        range = "no-limit"
    },
    // constraints
    new {
        year = "19\d{2}|2[01]\d{2}",
        month = "0[1-9]|1[0-2]",
        type = "apps|error"
    }
);
```

I've set year constraint to match years between `1900` and `2199`, and months so they actually have to specify a valid month `01` to `12`.

If you have any additional controllers you will have to define a default route as well and put controller constraint on this one or make controller name static (when just one applies).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along these lines

```
    ''# note, this is untested VB and might need some tweaking.
    routes.MapRouteLowercase("Base", "",
                             New With {.controller = "Home",
                                       .action = "Index",
                                       .year = UrlParameter.Optional,
                                       .paging = UrlParameter.Optional},
                             New With {.year = "[0-9]*"})
```

Then your controller would have something like

```
    Function Index(ByVal paging As String, ByVal year As Integer?) As ActionResult

        ''# do your pre-processing for paging and year.

        Return View()
    End Function
```